# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Docker vs Packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, packer

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk allows you to deploy apps using **Docker**. It also allows you to deploy apps using **Packer**.

It says you can use Packer to deploy apps with platforms that are not supported in Elastic Beanstalk. But isn't that what docker is popularly used for - to build your whole app environment from the group up with OS and libraries and everything.

Why or Why not should I use docker deployment vs packer deployment?

Comment: Docker/Packer aren't alternatives to each other. If your stack is based on EC2 images and AMIs then you would use Packer to build the image and then launch into EBS. If you're leveraging containers, then EBS allows you to launch with those. But you could also build your Docker images using Packer, if you needed a distributed method of building Docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Docker and Packer have different purposes.

**Use of Docker**- If you want to containerize your application, you use docker. If the app is simple enough such that the benefits are less than the complexity involved maintaining docker containers, don't use it.

**Use of Packer**- If want to create multiple platforms or images from single configuration, use packer. The existing configuration (for this reason the newly created platform), may contains docker as well.

**In relation to AWS Beanstalk:** Suppose you are running an application in AWS Beanstalk Java Platform. Recently there is a new platform that is getting popular in market and you want to try that out for your application. **But Beanstalk does not support that platform yet. Packer will be your friend here. Using it, you can create a custom platform in Beanstalk for yourself.** It will be easier and automated as it will use your existing platform configuration. You do not need to go through all the pain again to create the new platform from scratch.